# How to Generate Routes for Subcomponents Based on a Base Path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How to get the next route in vue-router

I have the following route: `/principal`

`{path: '/principal', component: Principal}`

Now, I need to drive other components that have the same url base,
the new url would be as follows:

`/principal/compa`

Is it possible to have a single base route be able to display the other components?

Something like this (I know that vue-router does not work like this), but how do you get this behavior?

`{
   path: '/principal', 
   component: Principal,
   subpath: {
    path: 'compa',
    component: 'CompA'
   }
}`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a `children` option in VueRouter constructor config to render Vue components with nested routes.

In that particular case, it would be:

```js
{
   path: '/principal', 
   component: Principal,
   children: [{
    path: 'compa',  // it would match /principal/compa
    component: CompA
   }]
}
```

From the vue-router doc:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      children: [ // <-- notice the children property
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Have a look at **[nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html)** for more details.

Comment: Hi, I understand the behavior, but if the parent component has content that I do not want to show ?, I just need to show the contents of the child component.

Because the way you suggest, I am showing the content of the father and son at the same time

Comment: @chalo It all depends on the structure of components. For instance, you can use a simple component containing only a `<router-view>` in its template for the base route, and then use an empty path in the `children` to set the component of the base route. In than case, others nested routes do not share the same view with the base route (that is specified by the empty path).